QED symbol in {aligned}[t] environment
I want to start my proof with a long derivation right of the bat, so I don't need the automatic line break when I use {align*} :

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    \begin{align*}
        (a+b)(c+d) &= a(c+d) + b(c+d) \\
        &= (ac + ad) + b(c+d) \\
        &= (ac + ad) + (bc + bd) \\
        &= ac + ad + bc + bd \qedhere
    \end{align*} 
 \end{proof}

\end{document}


I found that {aligned}[t] seems to give what I want regarding equations as it has no line break after "Proof":
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}   \hfil
        $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
            (a+b)(c+d) &= a(c+d) + b(c+d) \\
            &= (ac + ad) + b(c+d) \\
            &= (ac + ad) + (bc + bd) \\
            &= ac + ad + bc + bd &\qedhere
        \end{aligned} 
        $ 
    \end{proof}

\end{document}


However, the QED symbol is not properly flushed right in this version. Does anyone have a nice way to send the QED symbol within {aligned}[t] to its usual position (compared to its usual occurrence in the proof environment)?

@cfr I was planning to edit the code as you suggested, but some kind soul has already done it for me. Thanks Bryan.

You can update \abovedisplayskip to "unskip" a \baselineskip:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-\baselineskip}
\begin{align*}
  (a + b) (c + d) &= a (c + d) + b (c + d) \\
                  &= (ac + ad) + b (c + d) \\
                  &= (ac + ad) + (bc + bd) \\
                  &= ac + ad + bc + bd \qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}


Can we use the package mathtools instead of amsmath and the command '\SwapAboveDisplaySkip? Please advise

@MadyYuvi mathtools loads amsmath so it is not instead  and Swap is just \newcommand\SwapAboveDisplaySkip{\noalign{\vskip-\abovedisplayskip\vskip\abovedisplayshortskip}}

@daleif Much thanks

This works really well, thanks! Out of pure curiosity, is there no easy fix that works with {aligned}[t] ?
